# Should a CNAME return a page with a frame pointing to the target host name?

Tags: azure, dns, cname

I've created a web app on MS Azure and asked our admin to add a CNAME so our public host name (www.example.com) points to the one on MS Azure (ourapp.couldapp.net) now the problem is when a user visits the www.example.com the response is a page with a frame pointing to ourapp.cloudapp.net which causes a lot of problems (e.g. IE9, IE10 do not allow cookies to be stored) now my question is:

- Is it a normal behavior for that dns server to return such a page (I mean does the CNAME work like this) or perhaps the admin has done something wrong?
- Is there another way to achieve the same result?

Thank you very much for your answers. I'm googling for a few days now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your admin setup domain masking, not a CNAME record.  The "www" CNAME record needs to point to yourapp.couldapp.net and then you forward the root domain to www.yourdomain.com.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But since I'm not a network specialist I don't understand the part "then you forward the root domain to www.yourdomain.com" do I need to do something in my IIS?

Comment: this all happens at the DNS level